# Accessing environment variables in package.json

Tags: json, heroku, npm, environment-variables

Recently I started working on a pretty old application where API endpoint URL differs on each system.

Right now, my package.json looks like this:

```
"start": "cross-env API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:5000/api/v1 react-scripts start"
```

The problem is, this value is currently static so when I deploy the code into Heroku, it tries to connect my localhost. Instead, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
"start": "cross-env API_ENDPOINT={thisShouldBeDynamic} api/v1 react-scripts start"
```

Is there any way to do it?

Ps. react-app-scripts version is ^0.4.0 so I cannot rely on `.env` and believe me, you wouldn't want to update it.

Answer (score 4):

JSON format doesn't support templating itself, so you need to create a script which will opens `config.json`, update it and save back to same file.

You can start from https://www.npmjs.com/package/config-template and create your own template filler which retrieve env variables you need and add them to config file, then same a file.

Comment: So I should trigger a seperate NodeJS file with "prestart", update package.json with regex and kill the process?

Comment: Not sure about killing process as you have to write command, which shall have finite execution. I've gave you basic approach, it can be mostly any program language.

Answer (score 3):

You can alter your installation before it starts up with the `postinstall` NPM hook. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process

For instance:

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "node ./ops/heroku-build.js"
}
```

And then in that script, simply read the appropriate env variables. `process.env` holds all the Heroku environment variables. Use those to edit your `package.json`.